# Equipment to bypass control board of a LED plant light

Tags: led

I have a hydroponics growing system like [this](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/1005004368076989.html), but the LED light is misbehaving: it switches off seemingly randomly, sometimes just moments after I switch the system on, sometimes after a couple of hours or even days.

I would like to bypass the control board and connect them to a suitable power supply, which I would switch on and off as required.

There are two boards in the box. The first one is in the bottom of the box:
[image: bottom board]
There, DC1 is power supply (24V DC), DC2 is a connector for a water pump, and DC3 is a connector for the control board (and the lights) - it is a stereo jack.
The element on the right, with "251024" on it, is a sensor used for low-level warning.

The light has 70 LEDs, divided into two groups with separate connectors: 7 blue LEDs and 63 warm (mixture of red and yellow) LEDs:
[image: LED lights]

The control board is in the light assembly:
[image: control board]
There, the right connector is the power supply, with 24 V between '+' and J3 pins. The J2-B and J1-W connectors lead to the corresponding connectors on the light panel, with 'W' provided warm light and 'B' adding a blue component.
In addition, the board seems to control the pump: when the pump is running, there is ca. 4 V between 'J3' and 'C' pins on the power connector.

The system works in 3 modes, using a different lighting. For each of them, I have measured the voltage between 'J3' pin on the power input and the '+' and '-' pins on the light connectors, plus the current going to the light.

1. "Normal" mode - W: 23.0 V, 0.5 V,  0.26 A,  B: 23.0 V, 0.7 V,  0.19 A
2. "Enjoy" mode - W: 23.5 V, 1.9 V,  0.21 A,  B off
3. "Grow" mode - W: 23.2 V, 0.0 V,  0.34 A,  B off

Now, I would like to achieve something like the normal mode, potentially with a bit warmer light. I am OK with using 2 separate power sources for the two light types, if it simplifies things. (I could also live with the "grow" mode, using one power source.)

I was told that I should look for "constant current" power sources, but I do not know what do I need exactly.
I found some AC LED drivers that can output close to the required current (200 to 250 mA in 50 mA steps), but they have a wide range of output voltage (like 25-50 V) so I am not sure they would be suitable.

Moreover, the system can clearly manage this with 24 V (and 1 A) DC power supply, so there must be a way to use just this power and some extra components (resistors)?

So, my question is whether there is some easy way to do this, i.e, connecting the LED lights directly to a power source (possible with some resistors in between)? It should not cost much, given the price of a new system (currently on sale for ca. $30)...

Comment: measure the voltage going to the lamp module (from - to +) and see what that looks like. if you manage the voltage and the led panel doesn't get hot, you can likely drive it with CV instead of CC, with a small ballast resistor just in case...

Comment: The voltages between + and - on the light connectors are differences between the values are stated, i.e., 22.5V for "normal" (both lights), 21.6V for "enjoy", and 23.2V for "grow". (I measured those directly earlier and the values are 0.2V lower, but it could have been with the pump running...)

Comment: fair enough. so (24v - 21.6v) = 2.4v to drop on a resistor. Targeting 0.34A, that comes to 7 ohms. I would probably get a slightly adjustable 24v PSU like a meanwell, and use 2 half-watt 4ohm resistors in series to the LED panel, one on each of - and +. Then you can dial in your current by adjusting the voltage.

Comment: Is there nothing in the backside of the control board?

Comment: LIke you said... $30....  Just replace the whole darn thing ... It's not worth monkeying with.     You'll spend close to that just buying your 2nd power supply.  And what's your time worth?   I would hit that PCB with a soldering gun, touch up every joint.  Pins on C2 and C3 look like they're solder-starved.   Lousy solder joints are a VERY common issue with cheap import electronics.   If that fails to fix it... drop it in the round file and move on.

Comment: @KyleB: would you just touch the joints (i.e., warm them), or would you add some new solder as well?

Comment: @MichalKaut  Add solder to every joint you can access and hope that fixes it   ;)